# Direct Descendants with html agility pack

Tags: .net, html-agility-pack

I have a specific html node and i want to get the 2nd aka last direct descendant. So after writing `.Descendants("div")` i wrote `ls.Last()`. I actually got the last div in the 2nd descendant. Not what i am expecting. How do i get only the direct descendants? or how do i get the descendant with a specific classname? because "div.postBody" would be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath would give you what you want. So for direct descendants only you can use -

```
htmlNode.SelectNodes("/div");
```

Or if you need to search by specific classname then -

```
htmlNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='postBody']");
```